# The sum of specific nodes in a binary tree

Tags: python, binary-tree

If i am given a question to find the sum of nodes divisible by 6 in a tree with the function having the tree name as a variable.
How do i approach such a question in solving?
Should I search for the nodes then add them?
And should the function be in the class I created or outside it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a tree traversal (decide which order you like - pre/in/post-order, it doesn't matter), and during the traversal to sum up only the nodes divisible by 6.

Tree traversal complexity is `O(n)`. If you go with the "searching" approach, each "search" operation costs `O(log(n))`, and you need to go over all the nodes, so the total complexity will be `O(n*log(n))`.

Answer (score 0):

If the tree is binary tree, you can try this, the n-ary tree is similar.

```py
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, x):
#         self.val = x
#         self.left = None
#         self.right = None
def func(root: TreeNode) -> int:
  if root == None:
    return 0
  else:
    if root.val % 6 == 0:
      return root.val + func(root.left) + func(root.right)
    else:
      return func(root.left) + func(root.right)
```